# fortran 90 gfortran fatal error can't rename module file exists

Tags: module, compilation, fortran, gfortran

I'm trying to compile and run a fortran 90 code with gfortran on a windows 7 machine.

When I compile and link using

```
gfortran -I"myDir" -g -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -fimplicit-none -fbacktrace -fcheck=all -Wuninitialized
-Q -J"bin" parametricStudy.f90 -o LDCP
```

I get the following error:

```
Fatal Error: Can't rename module file 'bin/initializeubcs_mod.mod0' to 'bin/init
ializeubcs_mod.mod': File exists
```

If I delete the mod file in the folder 'bin', then it compiles without any problems, but I don't want to have to delete all of my .mod files in the folder every time I compile my code. What should I do?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Always use tag [tag:fortran] and only add the version when necessary to distinguish that your question is specific. For example that you cannot use Fortran 2008 but only Fortran 90.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using gfortran 4.9 or 4.9.1 I guess you're being bit by https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=62215 . In that case, please update to 4.9.2 where this issue is fixed.

Comment: Ahh, I think you're right. I'll accept once I confirm. Thank you!